# Laravel: Remove an attribute in returned result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have the following code:

```
$orders = Order::all();
return $orders;
```

This returns something like this:

```
[
     {
         "id": 123,
         "qr_code": "foo.png",
         "qr_code_url": "http://example.com/foo.png"
     },
     {
         "id": 112,
         "qr_code": "bar.png",
         "qr_code_url": "http://example.com/var.png"
     }
]
```

Note that `qr_code_url` is an appended attribute, and not an attribute stored in the database.

I want to return this collection back to the user without the attribute: `qr_code`, in this case. So like this:

```
[
     {
         "id": 123,
         "qr_code_url": "http://example.com/foo.png"
     },
     {
         "id": 112,
         "qr_code_url": "http://example.com/var.png"
     }
]
```

Looking at the collection functions, i can't seem to find an easy way to do this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

The only functions I have found close to what I want is: `except` and `forget`, but they seem to just work on a 1 dimension array. Not a collection result returned by a model.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can set your attribute as hidden on the model class (see [Hidding Attributes From Json](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json))

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = ['qr_code'];
```

The attribute will still be loaded, but it won't be shown in your collections.

If you don't want to make it permanent, you can use the `makeHidden()` eloquent method as described on the docs:

> #### Temporarily Modifying Attribute Visibility
>
> If you would like to make some typically hidden attributes visible on
>   a given model instance, you may use the makeVisible method. The
>   makeVisible method returns the model instance for convenient method
>   chaining:
>
> ```
> return $user->makeVisible('attribute')->toArray();
> ```
>
> Likewise, if you
>   would like to make some typically visible attributes hidden on a given
>   model instance, you may use the makeHidden method.
>
> ```
> return $user->makeHidden('attribute')->toArray();
> ```

Comment: `only` is just an inverse of `except` and neither one works  because they are not designed to act on an array of arrays.

Hidden works, but that makes it hidden for EVERY time I convert to JSON. Not just a one off.

Comment: @YahyaUddin but the response of AnyModel::all() is an collection, that's an array of arrays when converted. Both `only` and `except` methods should work fine!

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. And yes it's an array of an array. If it was `['id' => 10, 'qr_code' => 'foo', 'qr_code_url' => 'blah']` then it would work. But it's `[ [id => 10 ...], [id => 11 ...]]`. If I was doing `Order::first()` it would work.

Comment: You're right, looking better it doesn't work for this case, sorry.

Comment: You can use `makeHidden()` eloquent method to solve your problem, take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 17):

You can use

```
$model->offsetUnset('propertyName');
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$eloquentCollection->transform(function (Model $result) use ($forgetThisKey) {
    $attributes = $result->getAttributes();
    unset($attributes[$forgetThisKey]);
    $result->setRawAttributes($attributes, true);
    return $result;
});
```

Comment: In truth, I have to agree, a transformer class would be a more elegant solution.  I do _not_ feel like my answer should be the accepted one :P.  However it does address the question- so why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

When you build api the recommended way of controlling output data is to use [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com) transformers.

If it's to much and you want to keep it simple you can use laravel `pluck` method on collections.

Comment: I agree. Transformers are a game changer. Using transformers may seem like overkill at first, but once your data starts growing and getting more complex... the versatility and reusability of Transformers, especially when dealing with relations, really starts to shine. Definitely worth the 10 minutes it takes to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

have had experience with this too. I've found a good solution here.

But, if you like a one-liner solution, you can also use the ff methods of Eloquent's Model class:

```
setHidden(array $hidden)

Ex: $user->setHidden(['name'])
```